# Reducing margins for printing

Tags: windows, pdf, printing

I cannot reduce margins for printing and end up wasting a lot of space. Even when I try to scale the page it doesn't work.

e.g.,

[http://irma.math.unistra.fr/~loday/PAPERS/LodayVallette.pdf](http://irma.math.unistra.fr/%7Eloday/PAPERS/LodayVallette.pdf)

[http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/PAPERS/kmbooklatex.pdf](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/PAPERS/kmbooklatex.pdf)

What's worse is when I try to print 2x2 it seems about 50% of the space is wasted and the pages are almost unreadable(and there is no scaling of the individuals pages(pre-scaling) or changing of margins). I'd like to print 2x2 and essentially maximize each individual subpages size except for alternating left and right margins(for binding).

Any way to fix this? Clearly I could extract each page to an image and then scale but I shouldn't have to go through all that trouble to do something that should be relatively simple.

Comment: What product are you using for printing? Are you on Windows?

Comment: @harrymc yes, windows. I use various things. Tried everything I have but nothing lets me adjust the pages individually in a way I can reduce margins. It seems it has to do with certain pdfs but nothing lets me pre-modify margins or scale in 2x2 printing.

Comment: Why do you want to reduce margins? Is scaling the page up to be larger and ignoring the warning about printer-page overflow a solution?

Comment: @harrymc because the margins are like 3 inches and there is a huge amount of waste and the font then is smaller than it needs to be... and when one then prints 4 pages to side hits compounds the problem about 16 times. As I said, I cannot scale, it does nothing. I can scale down but that then only makes it worse. Please read what I typed in the question, I explain it all there.

Comment: Depending on the PDF viewer, you may be able to set a zoom factor when printing. Tried that yet? I don’t use Adobe’s reader anymore but I’m relatively sure it had a feature like that. If it didn’t work, how exactly did it not work?

Comment: @DanielB That is scaling factor and yes I've tried it and not just in acrobat. I mentioned that I tried that.

Comment: I can't speak to windows, nor your software, nor your printer. BUT there should be the option (in software, or printer settings) to "modify page properties (A4)", with the option to shrink margins, even to outside printer range. I use 0.5cm for print-targeted documents and 0.0 for documents only intended to be viewed on PC.

Comment: @mitts I can modify margins in some cases but it does not modify them when tiling the pages. The pdf's are there in the links. Try doing it. Try printing them with no margins and then 2x2 with no margins.... so that there is no empty marginal space at all in the pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### In Adobe Acrobat Pro DC

1. Navigate to a page in your document with full text coverage and minimum margins. *See Notes
2. Got to Organise pages
3. Set Page Boxes
4. Select constrain proportions
5. Change the margin incrementally until it is the preferred size
6. Select Page Range: All
7. Click OK

Pages are now roughly 6.5" x 9" (from 8.5" x 11")

A. Select print
B. Select printer Adobe PDF
C. Select 'Fit' (roughly 122% bigger)
D. Save the new file to your PC

The same process applies in any other PDF editor, although the language may vary.  The print part is standard 'fit to page' printing.

Hope that helps.

### Notes

**Acrobat Pro Version:**
These instructions are based on Adobe Acrobat Pro DC (2022.001.20117).  They may vary for older releases.

**Note on List Item #1**
*" 1. Navigate to a page in your document with full text coverage and minimum margins.
"*
Since you will be using the same 'crop' settings for all pages, you want to make sure the page you are using as your template for adjustments has maximum text coverage, and the minimum margins found in the doc.  This will insure that you don't crop your pages too small.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be what I am looking for. It's not under organize pages but print production in my version of acrobat. There is also an option that says remove white margins which doesn't work but it would be cool if there was a way to detect the true margins used(which would calculate it based on all the pages rather than me trying to figure it out).  [For example, I can't scroll through pages to check the margins and any changes resets all the settings to 0 so I have to remember them]. It can do "remove white margins" so I wonder if I can just do that and then find the largest page?

Comment: So I think now, once I do that it does work. The problem is that when I print 4 to a page there is still excessive margins. Not as bad since I removed excess space but I'd basically need to adjust the inner margins. It basically seems to add some margin to each of the subpages and this stacks the margins adjacently created a large middle gap(which means smaller text for no reason). The effect seems to be due to the aspect ratio of the page so I sort of just need to scale the width of a the page a little(I think I'll be ok with the distortion).

Comment: So to solve that I can actually, at least with format, print 3x2 and save paper. The only problem is that the hole punches eat in to the text a little so I need to add a little to the margin. I think I can print it to a pdf then print the pdf but add some margin to the left.

Comment: 1. To identify ideal cropping size, I simply spun through the pages and  selected a page with close to full page coverage.  I have updated the instructions to reflect that.

Comment: 2.  'True' margins?  It appears to me this is likely a scale 1:1 copy of a physical or digital book onto a larger p[age.  What you are calling 'margins' is space that is a combination of both the white space/margins in the original document added to the additional page real estate on the larger letter-sized page.  Whose to know what proportion of the white space came from the original page, and what portion was the delta between the different page sizes.  If you actually knew the original page size you would simply crop down to that precisely that size.

Comment: 3. 'Remove white margins'  wasn't helpful to me as the white space varied too much on each page.  Eyeballing a page with maximum coverage seemed more than adequate to me.  Given that there are headers and footers on many pages that provides a nice border for the likely top and bottom of the page.

Comment: How can I "skew" the text by stretching the document vertically? Is there a way to do that in Acrobat? I mean, I'm pretty happy with the 3x2 printing in this case but I imagine in general it would be nice to have some way to properly optimize the format. Ideally there would be a command(or app) that I could do that would let me easily configure all this stuff. Maybe acrobat allows for writing scripts and I can automate it. I just want to set page format and pre-page w-scale and h-scale along with reducing margins. I can reduce margins by using your method but I still need to set w and h scales

Comment: My mistake, you will need to skew it horizontally not vertically.   Can't see the benefit, will decrease legibility, increase file size, and not save any paper as it will likely need to be an image to skew.